# Read id starting with # in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I am scraping a web page, and the div that I need to access has `id="#abc"`.
I am using cheerio to scrape the page, so I need to do it in JQuery but it does not work:

```
$('##abc') // undefined
```

But it works with pure javascript:

```
getElementById("#abc") // works well
```

Comment: why ## when get id ?

Comment: @Shree Because the `id` starts with `#`?

Comment: because the id value is '#abc' and not 'abc'.

Comment: Use `$('#\\#abc')`

Comment: just out of curiosity - why is the id prefixed with `#` - seems really counter-intuitive

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/ something like that?

Comment: try `$("#\\#abc")`. It works

Comment: Wonderful, thanks all for your answers, $("#\\#abc") works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this `$('#\\#abc')` by escaping any special characters with the id.

[Check here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)

```js
$(function()
{
 var a  = document.getElementById("#abc")
 
 
 var b  = $('#\\#abc')
 
 $(b).val("test")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="#abc" />
```

Comment: You could now also add an explanation of *why* this code works, to set it apart from the comments that pointed out that this works.

Comment: @LucaKiebel, Yes I was trying to edit an answer and now I've added

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for input(hidden,text..)

```
$("[id='#abc']").val()
```

As @Scott Marcus Suggested

This for all non-form field elements:

```
$("[id='#abc']").html()
$("[id='#abc']").text()
```

Comment: `div` elements don't have a value. They have `.text()` or `.html()` (Jquery).

Comment: Yes it depend on element that id refer .

Comment: you should always explain code - never just post an answe

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$('[id="#abc"]');
```

Comment: you should always explain code - never just post an answer